# How to upload a binary file using native http in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native, ionic-native-http

Hi i want to send file using native http as binary not form data can you please guide me thorugh it how to do.

1. I am using ionic 6
2. Need to upload file using native http send as binary
3. Cant able to find proper solution.
   can any one guide me other ways to this?please don't suggest me formdata

Comment: and how are you picking your file? what is your File object looks like?

Comment: I am using multiple document picker converting the data into blob successfully but problem where i am facing is while sending to api i cant see any elegant process neither through nativehttp nor filetransferplugin and when i try using httpclient i am using ionic-native-http-connection-backend which isn't allowing me